# I can't copy texts by command+C in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, setting

I'm using Eclipse on Mac, version JUNO.
From some days ago, I can't copy texts by command+C.
The key bind of "copy" is binded to "command+C" when in Windows in my 'Keys' setting of Eclipse.
I can't understand what is wrong...
Please tell me what is wrong.

*To reset Key Bind and restart Eclipse,this problem is solved!!****

Comment: Does this shortcut work in other applications on your Mac?

Comment: It looks like this is some sort of bug. I can't use Command-C in my build of Eclipse (Aptana) either.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on CentOS =/